# Can a non-trivial algebraic variety carry a vector bundle whose total space is affine space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $Y\to X$ be an algebraic vector bundle. Suppose $Y$ is algebraically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ for some $n$. Does it follow that $X$ is algebraically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^m$ for some $m$?

Comment: Hi Anton! This sounds related to what is known as the Cancellation Problem, asking if $X\times \mathbf{A}^n \simeq Y\times \mathbf{A}^n$ implies $X\simeq Y$. The answer to the general question is no (Google "Danielewski surfaces") and it is studied quite extensively (see e.g. papers of Dobouloz and Jelonek). For $X = \mathbf{A}^m$ as in your case, the answer is yes for $m\leq 2$, no for $m>2$ in positive characteristic https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0483 , and as far as I can google, it is open for $m>2$ in characteristic zero. I'm hope someone more knowledgeable will weigh in.

Comment: As @PiotrAchinger says, this is unknown even for trivial bundles. In fact, your assumptions imply that the bundle must be trivial. Firstly, $X$ must be affine since a vector bundle always has a zero section. $X$ is also $\mathbb{A}^1$-contractible since $Y$, being affine space, is so Finally, any vector bundle on an $\mathbb{A}^1$-contractible (smooth) affine variety is trivial by a theorem of Morel. (There might well be a simpler proof.)

Comment: @ulrich indeed, the zero section gives a decomposition of the identity map $X \to Y \to X$ and the pull-back of the bundle to $Y$ is trivial because $Y$ is the affine space. So the pullback to $X$ must be trivial, which is the original bundle because $X\to X$ is identity.

Comment: Nice, it is indeed much simpler!

Comment: So, to sum up: a) $E$ is a trivial bundle over $X$ of  rank $n-m$.  b)  It is not known  for $m\gt 2$ whether $X$ is isomorphic as an algebraic variety to the affine space $\mathbb C^m.$ c) For $m\leq 2$ however we do know that $X=\mathbb C^m$.

Comment: Yes, it looks like we have an answer

Comment: @PiotrAchinger could you convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Summing up the discussion in the comments:

As user ulrich observed, the vector bundle has to be trivial. First, since $X$ is a closed subscheme of $Y\simeq \mathbf{A}^n$ via the zero section, it has to be affine. It is also smooth. Finally, it is $\mathbf{A}^1$-contractible since $Y$ is, since $Y\to X$ induces an equivalence in $\mathbf{A}^1$-homotopy. We conclude by a theorem of Morel (see Chapter 7 in *$\mathbf{A}^!$-algebraic topology over a field*, [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~morel/Prepublications/A1TopologyLNM.pdf)), saying that vector bundles on a smooth affine $\mathbf{A}^1$-contractible variety are trivial.

A simpler argument using Quillen-Suslin was given by Anton: $X$ is a retract of $Y \simeq \mathbf{A}^n$ via the zero section, and since every vector bundle on $Y$ is trivial, the same is true for $X$.

This turns the question into an important special case of the Cancellation Problem.

> **Cancellation Problem.** If $X\times \mathbf{A}^m \simeq Z \times \mathbf{A}^m$, can we conclude that $X\simeq Z$?

The answer to this general problem is **no** (there are famous counterexamples already in dimension two, known as Danielewski surfaces). However, in the special case where $Z$ is an affine space ($\mathbf{A}^{r}$, $r+m=n$ in our case) the answer is known to be **yes**  for $r\leq 2$, and open for $r>2$. (In positive characteristic, the answer is **no** for all $r>2$:  arxiv.org/abs/1208.0483 )

This answer is "Community Wiki".

Comment: Why does X have to be smooth a priori?

Comment: Because it is covered by Zariski opens on which the vector bundle is trivial, and $X\times \mathbf{A}^r$ is smooth if and only if $X$ is. Alternatively, apply Stacks Project tag 02K5 https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02K5 (with roles of $X$ and $Y$ switched and $S= \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf{C}$).